# How to open fragments on App with QR code scan

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

Hi I made gym app so the idea is that to implement QR Code scanner in the app so when I scan the QR code example for bench directly app to open the bench exercise every exercise is in different fragment so how can I do that I need to open a specific exercise by scanning exercise-specific QR codes.Thanks for your help also I can post source code of my app.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.hristijan.aleksandar.gymworkout.gymworkout">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="gymassistant" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
    <activity android:name=".BmiActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".QrActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

QRActivity

```
package com.hristijan.aleksandar.gymworkout.gymworkout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class QrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button scan_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
    scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity =this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Uri url = Uri.parse(result.getContents());
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.hristijan.aleksandar.gymworkout.gymworkout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,"fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.first_fragment) {
            setTitle("Home");
            FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,"bench");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.second_fragment) {
            setTitle("Bench Press");
            SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,"new1");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.third_fragment) {
            setTitle("Incline Bench Press");
            ThirdFragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,"new2");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.blank_fragment) {
            setTitle("About");
            BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,"new2");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.bmi_calculator) {
            setTitle("Bmi Calculator");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BmiActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.qr_activity) {
            setTitle("Scan QR Code");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,QrActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner . A customized view implementation of zxing .

Comment: and what can i do with that? can i open directly the fragment when some qr code is scanned? and how?

Comment: If get your question correct then Read carefully what i said. I said its a `View` so you can a view anywhere you want . In a `Fragment` or in a `Activity`. And they have a `Fragment` sample too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QRActivity.java

Change

```
Uri url = Uri.parse(result.getContents());
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(url);
startActivity(i);
```

into

```
Intent i = new Intent(QrActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("qrcode_result", result.getContents());
startActivity(i);
```

**Edit:**  You need to check `s` is `null`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("qrcode_result");


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


    if (s != null) {

        if (s.equals("Bench Press")) {
            setTitle("Bench Press");

            SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "new1");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } // else if(s.equals("...")){}

         else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"scanned QR code that doesn't exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setTitle("Scan QR Code");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QrActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    } else { // not using QR Code scanner
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

And it worked:)

Comment: App started crashing i take logcat  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Initialize `s` first, `private String s = "";` turn s as instance variable

Comment: How can i do that? i'm little noob

Comment: Check my edited answer, this prevent `String s` become `null`

Comment: can you check the code?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zLg5Ex3PsK2vj2S_IW_SHuwmRqOfq2mS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Man :) :)

Comment: One more Question man how can i make when it's scanned QR code that doesn't exist to show toast example "You scanned Wrong QR cODE or to go back to Qr Activity because now goes to MainActivity

Comment: Check one more time, if `s` not match any `String` value you want, run `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In QRActivity.java

```
scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       ScanFragment scanFragment = new ScanFragment();
       fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.scan_fragment,scanFragment);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }
});
```

In R.layout.activity_qr,
    You will add content layout for placing ScanFragment as above R.id.scan_fragment

**To add layout activity_qr**

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scan_fragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

**You wil create ScanFragment.java.Example here**

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
private String codeFormat,codeContent;
private final String noResultErrorMsg = "No scan data received!";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this.getActivity()).forSupportFragment(this);
    // use forSupportFragment or forFragment method to use fragments instead of activity
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt(this.getString(R.string.scan_bar_code));
    integrator.setResultDisplayDuration(0); // milliseconds to display result on screen after scan
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

/**
 * function handle scan result
 * @param requestCode scanned code
 * @param resultCode  result of scanned code
 * @param intent intent
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);


    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        codeFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        // send received data


    }else{
        // send exception

      }
    }
    }
```

You can also reference from  [blog]: http://blog.whomeninja.in/android-barcode-scanner-in-fragment/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
private static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
    int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("SCAN QR CODE", "Permission already granted!");
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
    //getActivity().setContentView( scannerView );
    return scannerView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            if (scannerView == null) {
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView( getActivity() );
                getActivity().setContentView( scannerView );
            }
            scannerView.setResultHandler( this );
            scannerView.startCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onResume();
}
```

This code in Fragment Class. I User ZXing .

And in the MainActivity i use FragmentManager to open it when app start.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.fragment_camera, new CameraFragment() );
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And code in MainActivity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_camera"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">

</RelativeLayout>
```